# Access to remote user's realm confirmed but RealmCollectionChange block not being executed - with repro code

Tags: swift, realm, xctest

I'm trying to exchange permissions between two SyncUsers to let them read objects from each other's realm.

I expect that once permissions are properly applied and access to the opposite user's realm is confirmed, a call to `realm.objects(Object.Type).observe { changes in ... }` should provide that user's objects.

But the block with RealmCollectionChange is never executed

[GitHub - project to reproduce](https://github.com/homathko/realm-syncpermission-test)

> EDIT Including complete code of SyncPermissionTest.swift

```
//
//  SyncPermissionTest.swift
//  realm-syncpermission-testTests
//
//  Created by Eric Lightfoot on 2019-10-31.
//  Copyright © 2019 HomathkoTech. All rights reserved.
//


import Foundation
import XCTest
import RealmSwift

let ROSHost = "<<your realm host>>" // Exclude 'https://', 'realms://'
let realmName = "synctest"
let userAName: String = "User22"
let userBName: String = "User23"
var userAId: String = ""
var userBId: String = ""

class SyncPermissionTest: XCTestCase {
    var userA: SyncUser!
    var userB: SyncUser!
    var realmA: Realm!
    var realmB: Realm!

    override func setUp () {
        super.setUp()
    }

    func testEverything () {
        print("Registering new users")
        registerUsers()
        print("Creating new realms")
        createRealms()
        print("Creating new objects")
        addSomeObjects()
        print("Reading some objects")
        readUsersOwnObjects()
        print("Not able to access other user's realm yet")
        connectToOtherUsersRealmShouldntWork()
        print("Now try exchanging mutual permission")
        exchangePermissionToReadEachOthersRealms()
        print("Now try accessing each other's realm again")
        connectToOtherUsersRealmShouldNowWork()
        print("Reading other user's realm")
        readOtherUsersObjects()
    }

    func registerUsers () {
        let exp_userACreated = XCTestExpectation(description: "\(userAName) registered")
        let exp_userBCreated = XCTestExpectation(description: "\(userBName) registered")

        let authURL = URL(string: "https://\(ROSHost)")!
        let userAcreds = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: userAName, password: userAName, register: true)
        let userBcreds = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: userBName, password: userBName, register: true)

        SyncUser.logIn(with: userAcreds, server: authURL) { user, err in
            XCTAssert(err == nil)
            XCTAssert(user != nil)
            self.userA = user!
            userAId = user!.identity!
            print("Created \(userAName)")
            exp_userACreated.fulfill()
        }

        SyncUser.logIn(with: userBcreds, server: authURL) { user, err in
            XCTAssert(err == nil)
            XCTAssert(user != nil)
            self.userB = user!
            userBId = user!.identity!
            print("Created \(userBName)")
            exp_userBCreated.fulfill()
        }

        wait(for: [exp_userACreated, exp_userBCreated], timeout: 60)
    }

    func createRealms () {
        let exp_realmForUserACreated = XCTestExpectation(description: "User A realm created")
        let exp_realmForUserBCreated = XCTestExpectation(description: "User B realm created")

        let realmURL = URL(string: "realms://\(ROSHost)/~/\(realmName)")!

        var userAConfig = self.userA.configuration(realmURL: realmURL, fullSynchronization: true)
        userAConfig.objectTypes = [Thing.self]
        Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: userAConfig) { realm, err in
            XCTAssert(err == nil)
            print("\(userAName).realm created")
            self.realmA = realm
            exp_realmForUserACreated.fulfill()
        }

        var userBConfig = self.userB.configuration(realmURL: realmURL, fullSynchronization: true)
        userBConfig.objectTypes = [Thing.self]
        Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: userBConfig) { realm, err in
            XCTAssert(err == nil)
            print("\(userBName).realm created")
            self.realmB = realm
            exp_realmForUserBCreated.fulfill()
        }

        wait(for: [exp_realmForUserACreated, exp_realmForUserBCreated], timeout: 60)
    }

    func addSomeObjects () {
        let names = ["Dude", "Man", "Bra", "Dingus", "Mangnolia", "Broseph"]

        func createRandomObjectsInRealm(realm: Realm, howMany: Int) {
            realm.beginWrite()
            for _ in 1...howMany {
                let thing = Thing(value: [
                    "name": names[Int.random(in: 0..<names.count)],
                    "age": Int.random(in: 0...1000)
                    ])
                realm.add(thing)
            }
            do {
                try realm.commitWrite()
            } catch (let err) {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
                XCTAssert(false)
            }
        }

        createRandomObjectsInRealm(realm: self.realmA, howMany: 10)
        print("Created some objects in \(userAName)'s realm")
        createRandomObjectsInRealm(realm: self.realmB, howMany: 10)
        print("Created some objects in \(userBName)'s realm")
    }

    func readUsersOwnObjects () {
        let exp_canReadObjectsFromUserAsRealm = XCTestExpectation(description: "\(userAName)'s realm contains objects")
        let exp_canReadObjectsFromUserBsRealm = XCTestExpectation(description: "\(userBName)'s realm contains objects")

        func readObjectsFromRealm (realm: Realm, expectation: XCTestExpectation) {
            let _ = realm.objects(Thing.self).observe { π in
                switch π {
                case .initial(let results), .update(let results, _, _, _):
                    print(Array(results))
                    if results.count == 10 {
                        expectation.fulfill()
                    }
                case .error(let err):
                    print(err.localizedDescription)
                    XCTAssert(false)
                }
            }
        }

        readObjectsFromRealm(realm: self.realmA, expectation: exp_canReadObjectsFromUserAsRealm)
        print("\(userAName) reads objects from \(userAName)'s realm")
        readObjectsFromRealm(realm: self.realmB, expectation: exp_canReadObjectsFromUserBsRealm)
        print("\(userBName) reads objects from \(userBName)'s realm")
        wait(for: [exp_canReadObjectsFromUserAsRealm, exp_canReadObjectsFromUserBsRealm], timeout: 60)
    }

    func connectToOtherUsersRealmShouldntWork () {
        let exp_UserAcannotConnectToUserBsRealm = XCTestExpectation(description: "\(userAName) can't connect to \(userBName)'s realm")
        let exp_UserBcannotConnectToUserAsRealm = XCTestExpectation(description: "\(userBName) can't connect to \(userAName)'s realm")

        // Connect UserA to UserB
        let userBRealmURL = URL(string: "realms://\(ROSHost)/\(userBId)/\(realmName)")!

        var userAConfig = self.userA.configuration(realmURL: userBRealmURL, fullSynchronization: true)
        userAConfig.objectTypes = [Thing.self]
        Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: userAConfig) { realm, err in
            print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "none")
            XCTAssert(err != nil)
            exp_UserAcannotConnectToUserBsRealm.fulfill()
        }

        // Connect UserB to UserA
        let userARealmURL = URL(string: "realms://\(ROSHost)/\(userAId)/\(realmName)")!

        var userBConfig = self.userB.configuration(realmURL: userARealmURL, fullSynchronization: true)
        userBConfig.objectTypes = [Thing.self]
        Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: userBConfig) { realm, err in
            print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "none")
            XCTAssert(err != nil)
            exp_UserBcannotConnectToUserAsRealm.fulfill()
        }

        wait(for: [exp_UserAcannotConnectToUserBsRealm, exp_UserBcannotConnectToUserAsRealm], timeout: 60)
    }

    func exchangePermissionToReadEachOthersRealms () {
        let exp_UserAGivesReadPermissionToUserB = XCTestExpectation(description: "\(userAName) gives read permission to \(userBName)'s realm") // Description incorrect, changed in original code
        let exp_UserBGivesReadPermissionToUserA = XCTestExpectation(description: "\(userBName) gives read permission to \(userAName)'s realm") // Description incorrect, changed in original code

        let userARealmURLStringToGivePermissionTo = "/\(userAId)/\(realmName)"
        let permissionToA = SyncPermission(realmPath: userARealmURLStringToGivePermissionTo, identity: userBId, accessLevel: .admin)
        userA.apply(permissionToA) { err in
            print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "no error")
            XCTAssert(err == nil, "userA.apply() -> Callback received with no error")
            exp_UserAGivesReadPermissionToUserB.fulfill()
        }

        let userBRealmURLStringToGivePermissionTo = "/\(userBId)/\(realmName)"
        let permissionToB = SyncPermission(realmPath: userBRealmURLStringToGivePermissionTo, identity: userAId, accessLevel: .admin)
        userB.apply(permissionToB) { err in
            print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "no error")
            XCTAssert(err == nil, "userB.apply() -> Callback received with no error")
            exp_UserBGivesReadPermissionToUserA.fulfill()
        }

        wait(for: [exp_UserAGivesReadPermissionToUserB,exp_UserBGivesReadPermissionToUserA], timeout: 60)
    }

    func connectToOtherUsersRealmShouldNowWork () {
        let exp_UserAcanConnectToUserBsRealm = XCTestExpectation(description: "\(userAName) can now connect to \(userBName)'s realm")
        let exp_UserBcanConnectToUserAsRealm = XCTestExpectation(description: "\(userBName) can now connect to \(userAName)'s realm")

        // Connect UserA to UserB
        let userBRealmURL = URL(string: "realms://\(ROSHost)/\(userBId)/\(realmName)")!

        var userAConfig = self.userA.configuration(realmURL: userBRealmURL, fullSynchronization: true)
        userAConfig.objectTypes = [Thing.self]
        Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: userAConfig) { realm, err in
            print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "no error")
            XCTAssert(err == nil)
            exp_UserAcanConnectToUserBsRealm.fulfill()
        }

        // Connect UserB to UserA
        let userARealmURL = URL(string: "realms://\(ROSHost)/\(userAId)/\(realmName)")!

        var userBConfig = self.userB.configuration(realmURL: userARealmURL, fullSynchronization: true)
        userBConfig.objectTypes = [Thing.self]
        Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: userBConfig) { realm, err in
            print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "no error")
            XCTAssert(err == nil)
            exp_UserBcanConnectToUserAsRealm.fulfill()
        }

        wait(for: [exp_UserAcanConnectToUserBsRealm, exp_UserBcanConnectToUserAsRealm], timeout: 60)
    }

    func readOtherUsersObjects () {
        let exp_userAcanReadObjectsFromUserBsRealm = XCTestExpectation(description: "\(userAName) can see that \(userBName)'s realm contains objects")
        let exp_userBcanReadObjectsFromUserAsRealm = XCTestExpectation(description: "\(userBName) can see that \(userAName)'s realm contains objects")

        func objectsRead (byUser: SyncUser, ofUser: SyncUser, expectation: XCTestExpectation) {
            // Connect UserA to UserB
            let ofUserRealmURL = URL(string: "realms://\(ROSHost)/\(ofUser.identity!)/\(realmName)")!
            var byUserConfig = byUser.configuration(realmURL: ofUserRealmURL, fullSynchronization: true)
            byUserConfig.objectTypes = [Thing.self]
            Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: byUserConfig, callbackQueue: DispatchQueue.main) { realm, err in
                print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "no error")
                XCTAssert(err == nil)
                let _ = realm!.objects(Thing.self).observe { π in
                    switch π {
                    case .initial(let results), .update(let results, _, _, _):
                        print(Array(results))
                        if results.count == 10 {
                            expectation.fulfill()
                        }
                    case .error(let err):
                        print(err.localizedDescription)
                        XCTAssert(false)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        objectsRead(byUser: userA, ofUser: userB, expectation: exp_userAcanReadObjectsFromUserBsRealm)
        print("\(userAName) reads objects from \(userBName)'s realm")
        objectsRead(byUser: userB, ofUser: userA, expectation: exp_userBcanReadObjectsFromUserAsRealm)
        print("\(userBName) reads objects from \(userAName)'s realm")
        wait(for: [exp_userAcanReadObjectsFromUserBsRealm, exp_userBcanReadObjectsFromUserAsRealm], timeout: 60)
    }
}

class Thing: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var age: Int = 0
}
```

- RealmSwift 3.20.0
- Realm Object Server 3.26.7
- Xcode 10.3
- iOS 12.4
- Cocoapods 1.5.3

Comment: Code should be included in the question. If a link breaks it will invalidate the question. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When you *read objects from each others realm*. What does that mean specifically? Realm reads from whatever Realm is set up in the config - are you syncing multiple realms with multiple users? If so, you will have to reconfigure realm to point at a different realm for each read - moreover, you will need to ensure all realm calls are encapulated in an autorelease pool.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll do that right now.

Comment: @Jay Yes as you can see in the code, I've gone through several transactions, using different configs. For instance, we must write objects to a realm before they can be read so in my case I had each user write objects to their own realm. In a subsequent transaction, a config is used for the 'remote' or 'other' or 'opposite' user in this example. I am mystified by the `@autorealease` issue...where is that documented pls if you have the time??

Comment: See the multitude of questions about [autorelease](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brealm%5D%5Bswift%5Dautorelease). Also, there's a few references for using [autorelease](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#compacting-realms) when you are doing things with the realm itself; changing, deleting etc. Also see [this discussion](https://forums.realm.io/t/copied-realm-not-returning-data/3041/18). Bottom line is that realm keeps a ref to its file as long as there are live objects. To change realms, you have to disconnect from the first realm and to do that all of the objects must be released.

Comment: Thanks again Jay. Are you able to review this code and point me in the right direction? This has been stonewalling me for a while. Would love an answer!

Comment: First thing is that I am not sure if Realm supports two authenticated users at the same time in the same app. For example, calling `SyncUser.current ` returns the current user - if you are doing `SyncUser.logIn` as shown in your code, which one is it? Not saying it doesn't but it's a question for Realm support unless you already know for sure. Second thing is that I don't see any reason to have multiple Realms for this use case. You could just as easily have a single realm that supports multiple users, each user having their own UserObject which correlates to their user data.

Comment: Ran of out space... Also, as soon as you do this `createRandomObjectsInRealm(realm: self.realmA` you a locked into realmA and cannot do anything with realmB. That's because when Realm has a live connection to it's objects you cannot work with another realm. Any interaction with realmA objects must be in an autorelease pool so they can be disconnected when you want to switch to realmB. Also, I don't see the code that actually switches your realms. See [Configuring Local Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#configuring-a-realm) for an example of how to change realm files

Comment: That’s a really good point about multiple users in the same test run. I’ll make some changes there. The app design calls for users with multiple realms (query based and full sync). Multiple realms provide data at once to other users. Those data streams are aggregated by a presenter into model views on the client. So a requirement of realm is that I can work with multiple realms (live connections) concurrently. What you say worries me! But I think this works since in this test run I successfully create objects in each users realm in a single function call (self.realmA and self.realmB coexist).

Comment: No, you cannot work with multiple realms concurrently unless adhering to the above condition of releasing the realm objects before connecting to another realm. e.g. if using the code  `let realm = try Realm()` and then `try! realm.write {`. which realm are we writing too, realmA or realmB? Oh - and it looks like you code it creating objects that have weak references since they only exist within the function that's doing the write so they can be released and realm will not 'hold onto' them. So for that specific case, it works.

Comment: Yeesh, I just figured out my expectations were arranged improperly. Connection was being closed because the test was over. But I am able to read the other user's realm now. Thanks so much for the discussion @Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection was closing immediately due to the test function ending, because I was incorrectly using one `XCTestExpectation` instance.